# GFCI seding low voltage to downstream devices

Tags: electrical, gfci, voltage

We just purchased a cabin and suddenly several lights stopped working. Initially I thought it was just the light over the kitchen sink. So I replaced the bulb and it still didn't work. I then checked the power panel for a tripped breaker and I didn't find one. I also discovered none of the receptacles and lighting circuits were labeled. Then I found other lights in the room were not working. So I pulled the switch plate on the sink light and inspected the wires. The wires were tight and it appeared the other lights must be feed from the kitchen light.  When I tested the circuit for power at the switch my meter displayed 10 to 12 volts on both sides of the switch.  Upon further investigation I found all the lights were on the same circuit and controlled from a GFI outlet in one of the bathrooms. When I reset the GFI in the bathroom all the lights worked. This must be why the GFI breaker was not tripped.

So my questions are;

one why was there a low voltage reading switch and down stream from a GFI that was tripped? (breaker not tripped)

My second question is why does my voltage light pen pick up voltage outside a wall within two radius of the last switch in the circuit when the GFI was tripped and doesn't light up when it is reset and the light works.  Usually the light pen has to be pretty close to a power source but not in this case.

Before this happened we did hear noises in the outside wall near the switch and thought a squirrel or a chipmunk may have chewed into cable.

Sorry for being so winded in the explanation.

Comment: Non-std wiring by a DIY. Stray voltage pickup on a high Z probe is common. Plug in a lamp and repeat.

Comment: The stray voltage or phantom voltage is a field created when electricity travels on wires a deenergised wire can pick up voltage from the field of a wire next to it this is how transformers work. the field induces A voltage on the wire the closer and longer distance the energized wires are together the higher the voltage measured will be.  Non contact detectors can sometimes detect the field several inches away, I have some detectors that go off when I am under power lines.